# How to find compatible alternative to string.atol in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make my *python2.x-Code* compatible with both 2.7 and 3.x. Currently I am stuck at some Code in Pmw.py (from python megawidgets). Have a a look at the first three entries of this dictionary:

```
_standardValidators = {
'numeric'      : (numericvalidator,      string.atol),
'integer'      : (integervalidator,      string.atol),
'hexadecimal'  : (hexadecimalvalidator,  lambda s: string.atol(s, 16)),
'real'         : (realvalidator,         Pmw.stringtoreal),
'alphabetic'   : (alphabeticvalidator,   len),
'alphanumeric' : (alphanumericvalidator, len),
'time'         : (timevalidator,         Pmw.timestringtoseconds),
'date'         : (datevalidator,         Pmw.datestringtojdn),
}
```

The first two entries contain "string.atol". My questions are:

1. In the python docs atol is introduced as a function ( `string.atol(s[, base])` ) , so there should be parentheses, which are missing here. So how is this syntax to be understood?
2. In python 3.2 this code raises the error:

   ```
   'numeric'      : (numericvalidator,      string.atol),
   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'atol'
   ```

   I already tried replacing the three occurences of "atol" with long, like suggested in the python docs, but that just raised the error:

   ```
   'numeric'      : (numericvalidator,      string.long),
   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'long'
   ```

   As I don't even understand the syntax, I'm quite helpless about what to try next. How is this code to be fixed, so that it works both in python 2.7 and 3.x?

Hope you can help me on that one.

Comment: "In python 3.2 this code raises the error:" - You forgot to say what the error was.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: he did say what the error msg was, though-- he pasted the AttributeError.  Formatting leaves a little to be desired, but it's his first. :^)

Comment: @DSM Right you are, my bad. The formatting somehow made my eyes just skip over it,

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that helps you the most (click on the green check by that question).

Comment: Oh, thanks for the hint. Btw, I'm not a he :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1: `string.atol` is the function *itself*: functions are first-class objects in python. The parentheses are only used for a call.

```
>>> import string
>>> string.atol
<function atol at 0x00B29AB0>
>>> string.atol("aab2", 16)
43698L
```

2: I think you must have misread.  long doesn't live in string, but there isn't a long in Python 3 anyway.  That's a relic of when Python distinguished between small integers and long integers in ways that could be seen from userspace. (That's what the "L" on the end of 43698L above means.)

Simply use int, i.e.

```
'numeric': (numericvalidator, int),
```

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Tradition says you should click the little checkmark beside the answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

When the parenthesis are missing, you're assigning the function itself, rather than the results of a function call.

Try replacing `string.atol` with `int`.

Comment: `long` doesn't exist in python 3.2, though.

Comment: @DSM, thanks - I thought so but wasn't sure. I'm still on 2.7.